# Meaning of "rat race" in the book of Rich Dad Poor Dad?

Tags: financial-literacy, financial-advisor, financial-statements

I want know what exactly rat race  is and why most of the people fall into that trap?

Comment: Rat Race is a common English term and not specifically to do with finance. You should maybe ask on our English Language site.

Comment: A few rats are running along racetracks, and the fastest rat wins.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its more about English phrase more apt on language.se or workplace.se

Comment: Rat race is running for something just because everyone else is ... I am working hard, because others are, I want more money because other have ... etc. When one forgoes what one needs and chases things just to chase ... stops enjoying what one has. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat_race

Comment: Welcome new user!  You can and should ask this excellent question on the English Language Learners site.  https://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: Watch Green Acres. Oliver always says he bought a farm to get away from the rat race in the city.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on English Language and Usage (English.SE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat_race) page says,

> A rat race is an endless, self-defeating, or pointless pursuit. The
>   phrase equates humans to rats attempting to earn a reward such as
>   cheese, to no avail. It may also refer to a competitive struggle to
>   get ahead financially or routinely.
>
> The term is commonly associated with an exhausting, repetitive
>   lifestyle that leaves no time for relaxation or enjoyment.

In his book Rich Dad Poor Dad, author wants people to get ahead of the rat race by properly managing their **Cash Flow** or by increasing **Assets**.

Comment: Hello!  Answering questions that should be migrated to another site, is probably not the best idea.

Comment: Still it's a very good answer for the question.